# Spring Social, Create connection for existing local users on signin

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-social

I am trying to allow existing local users to signin using Spring Social, primarily google, and automatically create a new userconnection if email matches local account.

I have only found examples for implicit signup (requires/creates a new account), new user signup (default action if SpringSocial fails to find a UserConnection) and the connect option while the current user is logged in.

How can I extend SpringSocial to let me check for existing social user / local user email match, create a user connection to existing local user and then sign them into both local and social?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the implicit sign up to find an account instead of creating a new one.

Modifying the code found for [implicit sign up](http://docs.spring.io/spring-social/docs/1.1.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#implicit-sign-up), you can do something similar to the following:

```
public class AccountConnectionSignUp implements ConnectionSignUp {

    private final AccountRepository accountRepository;

    public AccountConnectionSignUp(AccountRepository accountRepository) {
        this.accountRepository = accountRepository;
    }

    public String execute(Connection<?> connection) {
        UserProfile profile = connection.fetchUserProfile();
        Account account = accountRepository.findAccountByEmail(profile.getEmail());
        return account == null ? null : account.getUsername();
    }

}
```

You will need to implement `Account` and `AccountRepository` to support an email property, then use the repository to find account by email. If the repository cannot find an account, return null.